# JAX-WS implementation supporting java.util.List and Collections

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, apache-axis, glassfish-3

I'm looking for an implementation of JAX-WS that supports java.util.List and java.Util.Collections. I need my web service to return and manage collections: I tried Apache Axis2, but it seems to non handle that kind of objects.

To give more info, I'm using Eclipse IDE and Glassfish v3 Server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try apche CXF. AFAIK JAX-WS support of CXF is better than that of Axis2

Comment: Thanks Pradeep! But do you know more about its support of java.util.Collection e java.util.List ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link:
[Supported JAX-WS Types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBWorks4.html#wp82947)

Better to use array, where ever you are require to use Collections and have a sort of converter to convert array to collections and vice verse

Comment: Thanks Murugesh, but my application has too many dependencies on collection and I cannot change (it'd be not worth). Probably it's better to change technology (no more JAX-WS)?

Comment: If you use collections,there are no equivalent XML data types are available.Collections are language specific implementation.